# Spontaneous iPhone Factory Reset

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-id

While streaming Spotify to a BT device, my iPhone 14Pro with iOS17.2 suddenly rebooted to the configuration screen. If I don't select a language then it displays **"iPhone Locked To Owner"** with my asterixed appleID email address.
If I connect it to my MacBook the Music app does not recognize it, it offers the option to "Set Up iPhone".
On my laptop, in `SystemSettings/AppleID/Devices/NameOfPhone/` I get "**Device not found / The device you selected is not associated with your account**".
The **FindMy App** still has it listed but location data is stale and "**Play Sound**" has no effect.
Is there any way to restore this phone or have I lost all app data? Is there any way to tell if this is hardware related?

Comment: Not a big deal, really.  Go ahead and activate it, then restore your backup to it.  You do back up a mobile device, right?

Comment: Let’s get you a strategy to order your questions. We strongly prefer one question per question, but hopefully my answer will let you decide one path to then ask follow on question of any of the questions you asked here alone. You can let us know if you have backups or not in that case and narrow each next question you ask to one topic only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer each of your three questions, you may lose data as they are not solved with the same techniques. Power down the device and use a computer.

1. Before you start, see if there are any local backups of the device to any computer you trusted in the last - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204215
2. Check iCloud for synchronized data - https://www.icloud.com/
3. Check iCloud for backups of the device - https://support.apple.com/guide/icloud/view-and-manage-backups-mm122d3ef202/icloud
4. Borrow an iPad or phone you can erase and try setting it up from backup / iCloud.

I would set aside all attempts to activate it or test the hardware until after you decide to seek data recovery from the device. You likely will want professional help based on the details you included here on the various issues coupled with the risk of permanent data loss intrinsic from the likely next steps you will have to take.